# Можно ли запретить ввод символов (кроме числовых и точки) в окне WPF, не применяя при этом обработчик события?

Tags: c#, wpf

я новичок в разработке WPF-приложений.
Вопрос сам дан в заголовке. Необходимо чтобы при вводе в ячейку таблицы пользователь мог вводить только числа. Подсветка ячейки красным тоже не подойдет, нужно прям ограничение вводимых символов. Можно ли это реализовать без затрагивания файла xaml.cs?

Comment: Добро пожаловать на сайт, Анна. Вот полезная ссылка, чтоб задать качественный вопрос на ресурсе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - ознакомьтесь пожалуйста.

Comment: _Можно ли это реализовать без затрагивания файла xaml.cs?_ - нет. https://stackoverflow.com/q/841293/12888024

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Создать Настраиваемый элемент управления (не Пользовательский элемент управления) на базе TextBox. Потом, при его использовании, xaml.cs будет всегда пустым

Comment: По факту в Настраиваемом элементе управления весь код генерируется, потом ручками дописать пару строк и элемент для ввода чисел и разделителя готов

Answer (score 0):

У меня на avalonia реализована данная функция (wpf подобное), я привязывал к свойству текста переменную, и в сеттере делал обработку данных, самое главное это сделать до this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged (аналог INotifyPropertyChange), чтобы не символ даже не появлялся на милисикунду. У меня тут строковая стринговая переменная тк пользователь может вводить и текст и числа

```
     public string? AutoNumInitValue
        {
            get => _autoNumInitValue;
            set
            {
                if (TypeOfAutoNum == 0)
                {
                    if (!value.All(Char.IsDigit))
                    {
                        value = "0";
                    }
                }
    
                if (TypeOfAutoNum == 1)
                {
                    if (!value.All(Char.IsLetter) || value.Length > 1)
                    {
                        value = "";
                    }
                }
    
                this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _autoNumInitValue, value);
          }
```